# D3 draw circles around arc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

[image][image]

```
const pathSVG = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 791.558)
        .attr("height", 104.254);
    
    pathSVG.append("path")
        .attr("id", "one") //Unique id of the path
        .attr("d", "M-5723-3100.181s26.431,4.927,103.481-16.125c0,0,116.022-38.969,215.919-9.854,0,0,112.888,31.354,150.517,27.323,0,0,60.028.9,143.8-23.292,0,0,85.26-34.489,177.843,21.344v66.9L-5723-3032.707Z") //SVG path
        .style("fill", "#fff4e4")
        .attr("transform", `translate(5723, 3136.961)`);

pathSVG.append("text")
            .attr("x", 6)
            .attr("dy", 20)
            .append("textPath")
            .attr("xlink:href", "#one")
            .style("text-anchor", "start")
            .text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry");
```

Here instead of text, continuous circles should be coming, how we can achieve this?

Comment: Can you post a picture illustrating the desired result?

Comment: Added illustrating image

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Cubic Bezier (4 points) example:

```js
const points = [{x: 0, y: 100}, {x: 100, y: 0}, {x: 200, y: 200}, {x: 300, y: 100}];

const cbPoint = t => {
  const x = points[0].x * t * t * t + 
    points[1].x * 3 * t * t * (1 - t) +
    points[2].x * 3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t) +
    points[3].x * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t);
  const y = points[0].y * t * t * t + 
    points[1].y * 3 * t * t * (1 - t) +
    points[2].y * 3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t) +
    points[3].y * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t);  
  return {x, y};
} 

const RADIUS = 7;
const OFFSET = 25;
const WAVES = 2;

const svg = d3.select('svg');
const path = `M ${points[0].x},${points[0].y} C ${points[1].x},${points[1].y}   ${points[2].x},${points[2].y} ${points[3].x},${points[3].y}`;
for (let index = 0; index < WAVES; index++) {
  const g = svg.append('g');
  g.attr('transform', `translate(${50 + index * 300}, 0)`);
  g.append('path').attr('d', path).style('fill', 'none').style('stroke', 'black');
  for (let t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.1) {
    const {x, y} = cbPoint(t);
    g.append('circle')
      .attr('r', RADIUS)
      .attr('cx', x)
      .attr('cy', y + OFFSET)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="200" >
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. If we have to increase the arc width how we can do it. In your example 11 circles are there, if I want to 50 circles, how to add more curve?

Comment: @copycat see my updated answer